# Where is best to place the array variables that make up my app's data model?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, data-modeling

My iOS application called 'Thunder' is growing in complexity and I'm wondering whether there is a best practice I'm unaware of regarding data modeling. I don't know where to store my array variables.

'Thunder', as it is now, allows the user to record an audio clip and publish it to their timeline (`Home`).

Project structure (https://github.com/makhfib/Thunder)

```
    Thunder
    -- AppDelegate
    -- TabBarViewController
    -- Home
    ---- AudioClipViewController
    ---- AudioClipCell
    ---- HomeViewController
    -- Record
    ---- RecordViewController
    -- Library
    ---- LibraryViewController
    -- DataModel
    -- AudioPlayer
    -- AudioClip
      ...
```

Until now, `DataModel` held the array variable containing the audio clips published by the user. However, I'm adding a new functionality:

```
Users will be able to add new playlists to their library.
```

This requires an array of arrays. But I don't know whether I should keep placing my variables at `DataModel`. This question might sound stupid, but bare in mind that I'm thinking about the future. I would like to know how to handle situations like this when my application fattens up.

Where is best to place the array variables that make up my app's data model? What do I have to ask myself in order to make the best decision looking forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What for is your Data Model? I think your model should like similar to this:

```
struct UserInfo {
    var playlists: [Playlist]
    // MARK: Other content
}

struct Playlist {
    var clips: [AudioClip]
    // MARK: Other content
}

struct AudioClip {
    // MARK: Content
}
```

With this kind of model it is easier to work, or save in DB e.g. Realm, or Core Data.

Comment: Andrew, do you suggest I create a swift file for each structure?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be the best variant

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I certainly took your advice!

Comment: Glad to help you, you can close your issue by accepting an answer)